# NativeScript - How to Convert Magnetic Heading Degrees to True Heading Degrees

Tags: swift, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

**I am using Nativescript to Develop an IOS App**

**I am getting the magnetic Heading Degrees from the CLLocationManager**

**Location.service.ts**

```js
import * as geoLocation from "@nativescript/geolocation";

@Injectable()
export class LocationService {
    private locationManager : CLLocationManager;
    constructor() {
      this.locationManager = CLLocationManager.alloc().init();
      this.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 3;
      this.locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1;
      this.locationManager.headingFilter = 0.1;
    }

      getHeading(): number {
    return this.locationManager?.heading?.magneticHeading;
}

    convertDegreesToDirectionText(direction: number): string {
        if (direction == null) {
            return "N/A";
        }
        if (direction > 337.5) {
            return "North";
        }
        if (direction <= 22.5 && direction >= 0) {
            return "North";
        }
        if (direction > 22.5 && direction < 67.5) {
            return "Northeast";
        }
        if (direction >= 67.5 && direction <= 112.5) {
            return "East";
        }
        if (direction > 112.5 && direction < 157.5) {
            return "Southeast";
        }
        if (direction >= 157.5 && direction <= 202.5) {
            return "South";
        }
        if (direction > 202.5 && direction < 247.5) {
            return "Southwest";
        }
        if (direction >= 247.5 && direction <= 292.5) {
            return "West";
        }
        if (direction > 292.5 && direction < 337.5) {
            return "Northwest";
        }
        return "Could not determine direction.";
    }

  startUpdatingLocation(): void {
    this.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();
  }

  stopUpdatingLocation(): void {
    this.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
  }

  startUpdatingHeading(): void {
    this.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading();
  }

  stopUpdatingHeading(): void {
    this.locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading();
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationService } from './location.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-details',
  templateUrl: './item-detail.component.html',
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  item: Item;
  constructor(private locationService: LocationService) {
    this.locationService.startUpdatingLocation();
    this.locationService.startUpdatingHeading();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {  
     console.log('Magnetic Heading',this.locationService.getHeading());
     console.log('Magnetic Heading Text',this.locationService.convertDegreesToDirectionText(this.locationService.getHeading()));
  }

}
```

**How can i convert the magnetic heading degrees to true heading degrees ?**

**I do not want to use this.locationManager?.heading?.trueHeading; because true heading depends on the location services and gps to get the value and sometimes it returns -1 when it cannot determine the location, where as magnetic heading value always returns a value as it uses the device magnetometer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to convert magnetic heading to true north without knowing where the location is, since [magnetic declination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_declination) varies depending on where you are on Earth, and over time.